# Python installed for all users or current user only?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, registry, python-install

Using Python, How can I programmatically find whether the Python installed in my PC is installed for all users or for current user only?

Comment: I'm a Linux user, but couldn't you go in your PATH variable and see if it's added for just a user, or globally? First thought. Haven't used Windows since.. 2011 though.

Comment: For all user python will be installed in program files, for the current user, it will be in appdata.

Answer (score 6):

If you have installed Python for all users, You should install python in this folder:

> C:\Python27

Same as image

[image]

for more details check [this tutorial](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Part-1-Python-3-6-3-7-and-pip-installation-under-Windows)

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the Python executable is located in the user's home directory. The location of the home directory is retrieved by using the [`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) method. The location of the Python interpreter is retrieved by using the [`sys.executable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) method.

The following function returns `True` if the Python interpreter was installed within the user's home directory, and `False` otherwise. It works under Linux, and should work under macOS and Windows (but I didn't test those).

```py
import sys
import os

def user_python():
    try:
        return sys.executable.startswith(os.path.expanduser("~"))
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

The exception is needed because according to the documentation of `sys.executable()`, it may return `None` under some circumstances.

EDIT 2018-12-08: it works on Windows 10.